# Defining Bytes in GCC Inline Assembly in Dev-C++(.ascii in AT&T syntax on Windows)

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, dev-c++, att

The code below is just showing a Message Box on the screen.
The addresses are hardcoded to facilitate:

```
int main ()
{
    asm("xorl %eax, %eax        \n"
        "xorl %ebx, %ebx        \n"
        "xorl %ecx, %ecx        \n"
        "xorl %edx, %edx        \n"
        "pushl %ecx             \n" //$0x0
        "pushl $0x20206c6c      \n" //"  ll"
        "pushl $0x642e3233      \n" //"d.23"
        "pushl $0x72657375      \n" //"resu"
        "movl %esp, %ecx        \n" //store "user32.dll" address in %ecx
        "movl $0x7c801d7b, %ebx \n" //store address of LoadLibraryA in %ebx
        "pushl %ecx             \n"
        "call *%ebx             \n"
        "movl $0xef30675e, %ecx \n"
        "addl $0x11111111, %ecx \n"
        "pushl %ecx             \n"
        "pushl $0x42656761      \n"
        "pushl $0x7373654d      \n"
        "movl %esp, %ecx        \n"
        "pushl %ecx             \n"
        "pushl %eax             \n"
        "movl $0x7c80ae40, %ebx \n"
        "call *%ebx             \n"
        "movl %esp, %ecx        \n"
        "xorl %edx, %edx        \n"
        "pushl %edx             \n"
        "pushl %ecx             \n"
        "pushl %ecx             \n"
        "pushl %edx             \n"
        "call *%eax             \n"
        "xorl %eax, %eax        \n"
        "pushl %eax             \n"
        "movl $0x7c81cb12, %eax \n"
        "call *%eax             \n"
    );
}
```

(I didn't comment all the code because my question is not really about the code)

My question is: Is there a way to write the string "user32.dll" in assembly inline without pushing manually to the stack? I mean like this in NASM: `db 'Hello'`

I know that in AT&T syntax I could do `.ascii 'Hello'` or `.string 'Hello'` but how about in gcc inline?

Please note that I'm using Dev-C++ on Windows XP SP3

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, by making use of assembler directives inside your inline assembler.  The trick is in putting the string in the right place (the data section), which you can do by switching using `.section .data`, and then switching back again with `.section .text`.

You must give the data a label so that you can refer to it; I would recommend using the local label syntax here (where the label is a number, e.g. `1:`, and you reference it as either `1b` for the first `1:` label backwards, or `1f` for the first `1:` label forwards - see the [GNU assembler documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Symbol-Names.html) for more details).

Like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  asm(".section .data      \n"
      "1: .asciz \"Hello\" \n"
      ".section .text      \n"
      "pushl $1b           \n"
      "call _puts          \n"
      "add $4, %esp        \n"
     );
  return 0;
}
```

I don't have a Windows system handy to test this on, but it compiles OK and looks like it should be doing the right thing using a MinGW cross-compiler on Linux (I believe Dev-C++ is based on MinGW).

Note: this technique is generally applicable when using a GNU toolchain.  If you're building ELF binaries (e.g. native Linux), there is a neater way to switch back to the text section, which is to use `.previous`, which means "whatever the section before the previous `.section` was".  (The above example works on Linux if you change `_puts` to `puts` to account for different symbol prefixing conventions.)

Comment: Cool! Does "1:" means it's a label to the address of the string? Is the instruction "pushl $1b" pushing the address of "Hello"? What ".previous" do? Thanks!

Comment: ": Does ".previous" works on Windows? I'm not able to.. I'm using Dev-Cpp Portable

Comment: @jyzuz: no, it seems not; sorry about that.  I've updated my answer with a way round that.  `1:` is indeed a label, and `1b` refers to it (see the assembler documentation I linked to in my updated answer); so yes, `pushl $1b` pushes the value of the label - which is the address of the string - as a constant onto the stack.