# gcc inline assembler define string

Tags: c, string, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I try to define string out of .text section. It's compiled with no error but when I disassemble with gdb , I get bad instruction.
Here , it's code in c :

```
void main(){
    __asm__(
            "jmp .+0x35;"
            "pop %rsi;"
            "mov %rsi, -0x10(%rsi);"
            "movq $0x0,-0x8(%rsi);"
            "mov -0x10(%rsi), %rax;"
            "lea -0x10(%rsi), %rcx;"
            "mov $0x0, %edx;"
            "mov %rcx, %rsi;"
            "mov %rax, %rdi;"
            "mov $0x3b,%eax;"
            "syscall;"
            "mov $0x0,%ebx;"
            "mov $0x1,%eax;"
            "syscall;"
            "call .-0x33;"
            ".string \"/bin/bash\";"
    );
```

}

disassemble :

```
   0x0000000000400494 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400495 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400498 <+4>:     jmp    0x4004cd <main+57>
   0x000000000040049a <+6>:     pop    %rsi
   0x000000000040049b <+7>:     mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rsi)
   0x000000000040049f <+11>:    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rsi)
   0x00000000004004a7 <+19>:    mov    -0x10(%rsi),%rax
   0x00000000004004ab <+23>:    lea    -0x10(%rsi),%rcx
   0x00000000004004af <+27>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x00000000004004b4 <+32>:    mov    %rcx,%rsi
   0x00000000004004b7 <+35>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004004ba <+38>:    mov    $0x3b,%eax
   0x00000000004004bf <+43>:    syscall
   0x00000000004004c1 <+45>:    mov    $0x0,%ebx
   0x00000000004004c6 <+50>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x00000000004004cb <+55>:    syscall
   0x00000000004004cd <+57>:    callq  0x40049a <main+6>
   0x00000000004004d2 <+62>:    (bad) ( **here is define string** )
   0x00000000004004d3 <+63>:    (bad)
   0x00000000004004d4 <+64>:    imul   $0x68736162,0x2f(%rsi),%ebp
   0x00000000004004db <+71>:    add    %cl,%cl
   0x00000000004004dd <+73>:    retq
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: I wouldn't really call that C.

Comment: Did you except the encoding of "/bin/bash" to disassemble into something meaningful?

Comment: I except the address of "/bin/bash" ( somewhere's in memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   0x00000000004004cd <+57>:    callq  0x40049a <main+6>
   0x00000000004004d2 <+62>:    (bad) ( **here is define string** )
   0x00000000004004d3 <+63>:    (bad)
```

> How can I avoid this error?

If you don't want the string data appearing directly in the code (`.text`) section then you can use the [.section](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC119) directive to switch to the `.data` section, store the string, and then (optionally) switch back to `.text` again if you need to use the address of the data in more inline `asm` code:

```
        "call .-0x33;"
        ".section .data;"
        "1: .string \"/bin/bash\";"
```

This is described well by the accepted answer to [Defining Bytes in GCC Inline Assembly in Dev-C++(.ascii in AT&T syntax on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712062/defining-bytes-in-gcc-inline-assembly-in-dev-c-ascii-in-att-syntax-on-window)